# Regex - Extract also URLs with www

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, web, url

I use this regex to find URLs:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Problem is, that it doesn't find urls which start with www.

How can I solve this?

Here is my data [source](https://controlc.com/91acc839) that I need to extract urls from.

Comment: can you provide example of input that works with and input that does not works. In other word some expected input and output

Comment: Everything what begins with http, ftp, https works.
For example this works: http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
But this doesn't work: www.w3.org/2005/Atom

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Here is text: https://controlc.com/91acc839
Try your code and you will see it extract numbers for some reason. Try it online: regex101.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the provide xml file you come with in your comment.

There are couple of issues with your file, beside starting with https, http and www, it contains urls that start with download.somedomain.com, marketplace.somedmain.com, so it is inconsistence. the other issues is the ending of the the url can end with ., </, it does not have spaces after ending the url and it does not have a pattern to go through it line by line or chunk by chunk.

And last thing it contains duplicates.

The way I chose to solve, by chopping regex in 2 parts:

One part take all urls that start with valid url, with out looking at the end of it.
The second part take care of the valid url of what is remained from first part.
Regarding duplicates, I used hashset for that.
The solution does not consider specific tags in the xml or specific contain, it just care about urls in content.

Here is the solution:

```
HashSet<string> urls = new HashSet<string>();

var beginWith = new Regex(@"\b(?:(http|ftp|https)?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match item in beginWith.Matches(input))
{
    var endWith = new Regex(@"([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?");

    foreach (Match url in endWith.Matches(item.ToString()))
    {
        urls.Add(url.ToString());
    }
}
```

The code here can in deed be reduced and improved. I leave it for your fantasy.

Here is the final and  5 first urls output of the file:

```
www.w3.org/2005/Atom
marketplace.xboxlive.com/resource/product/v1
www.xbox.com/live/accounts
download.xbox.com/content/images/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802534307d4/1033/boxartlg.jpg
download.xbox.com/content/images/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802534307d4/1033/boxartsm.jpg
etc.....
```

Comment: I have tried this before. Yeah, it catch www. links, but also extract numbers from my file.
Here is the file from what I am extracting: https://pastebin.com/Z2LSZtdn

Answer (score 0):

Well, just check if your string contain "https://" or "http://", if not, add https:// at the beginning ^^

```
        string url = "";

        if (!url.Contains("https://") || !url.Contains("http://"))
        {
            url.Insert(0, "https://");
        }
```